# Firebug Lite not working in IE8 - Access denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firebug

1. As stated in the title, Firebug Lite `1.4`, `1.3` and latest throw an error in `IE 8.0.6001` on page load. The Firebug file is locally used.
2. When using the online file `http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js` I get an alert a couple of times stating: `Stop running this script? A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.` When clicking to wait for the script, after 5 alerts, it works.

What to do in any case?

---

**Edit:**

I only use Firebug when it is a IE:

```
if(isset($_GET['firebug']) && preg_match('/MSIE/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // $strFirebugLite = "<script type='text/javascript' src='../../client/lib/firebug-lite/firebug-lite.js'></script>";
    $strFirebugLite = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js'></script>";
}
```

Then I add the string to my page. Without binding Firebug in, everything works fine.

---

**Edit 2:**

Maybe the question is unclear: The problem is not my custom JavaScript code, but the use of Firebug itself, the adding of the `<script> ...` to my page.

---

**Edit 3:**

```
     <html><head><title>Title</title>

      <link  id="visiLibSkin"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/03/style.css">
      <style id="ext_style"></style>
      <script  language="JavaScript" src="../../client/visiSkin.js"      type="text/javascript"> </script>
      <script  language="JavaScript" src="../../client/visiFunc01.js"    type="text/javascript"> </script>
      <script  language="JavaScript" src="../../client/visiClass01.js"   type="text/javascript"> </script>
      <script  language="JavaScript" src="../../client/julz_visiWizard.js"   type="text/javascript"> </script> 
      <script  language="JavaScript" src="skin/03/style.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js'></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../client/lib/extjs/resources/css/ext-all-gray-scoped.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/x/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/deftjs/deft.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/x/x.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/x/test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../client/lib/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../client/lib/codemirror/lib/util/simple-hint.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/codemirror/lib/util/closetag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../client/lib/codemirror/lib/util/formatting.js"></script>
<script  language="JavaScript" src="skin/03/visiCalendar.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

---

**Edit 4:**

I am now also getting the error, that an object in `line 1354 char 131` is not supporting an attribute or function (using `http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js`)

Note: I am not yet doing anything in Firebug, just loading my page.

Comment: Can you show where you're using `$strFirebugLite`

Comment: Why are you using Firebug lite on IE8 when it has a built in console? Yes it is missing a few console lines, but those can be hacked in.

Comment: Because it lags, crashes and is little help. I just wanted to try Firebug. Firebug works here great at version 1.2 by the way!

Comment: @epascarello: Because IE8's built in "console" sucks, hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version `1.3` works. This version is sufficient currently. Version `1.4` still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the code, but it looks like you have some code that is running slowly..as stated by the error. Modern browsers have optimized JavaScript engines and are most likely avoiding the situation you're seeing in IE8.

> Internet Explorer monitors the number of statements that have been
>   executed by a script. When a maximum number of statements have been
>   executed, 5 million by default, the long-running script dialog is
>   displayed

Nick Zakas explains a few reason nicely [here](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html):

> **Too much DOM interaction**
>
> DOM manipulation is more expensive than any
>   other JavaScript process. Minimizing DOM interactions significantly
>   cuts the JavaScript runtime. Most browsers update the DOM only after
>   the entire script has finished executing, which slows the perceived
>   responsiveness of the web page to the user.
>
> **Loops that do too much**
>
> Any loop that either runs too many times or
>   performs too many operations with each iteration can cause
>   long-running script issues. It helps separate out functionality
>   whenever possible. The effect is worsened when loops are used to
>   perform DOM manipulations, sometimes causing the browser to completely
>   freeze without ever showing the long-running script dialog.
>
> **Too much recursion**
>
> JavaScript engines put a limit on the amount of
>   recursion that scripts can use. Rewriting the code to avoid recursion
>   helps ameliorate the issue.

Comment: Have added the code, but there is nothing special at it and as stated without the Firebug Lite, everything works fine.